# Invoking WCF service in browser similar to asmx

Tags: wcf

I have made a WCF service in NET 4.0 and it returns the XML, I have tested it using SoapUI and i can see the required response xml. But my WCF service would be called by 3rd party software and they want to use it through a URL like asmx.  I have googled and found that i need to make using REST guidelines. However i have not found a proper link showing making web-service using REST and then accessing the method from the browwer similar to web services.

**Below is the interface code which i have used to return the format in XML**

```
public interface IService1
{

    [WebGet(
        UriTemplate = "/GetDocument/",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]

    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
    XmlElement GetDocument();

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

**Below is my config settings.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="BritishLandXML.BritishLandXML1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BritishLandXML.IService1" />        
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="rest">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this and what exact settings will be required.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: How do I host the WCF Rest service in IIS 7.0? How will the third party access my service. I created the WCF Rest service and i viewed it in browser by right clicking the svc file in the solution and it was fine.